# IP Address delete - RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, networking, ip, centos-7

I am trying to install a distribution of Kubernetes with OVS. During the installation, the script tries to execute `ip addr del 65.109.33.184/32 dev enp41s0`, The command fails with Error `RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address`.

OS is Centos78 or Centos79. OVS version the script tries to install is 2.12. Kernel version 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64.

`ip addr` before installation:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp41s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:c0:b2:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 65.109.33.184/32 scope global enp41s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:4f9:5a:1f23::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:fec0:b273/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any advice please ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with similar symptoms, which I did solve. But it is probably not a fix for the problem which you describe. In my case, the error was the lack of CIDR subnet number for an IPv6 address.

```
root@host1:~# ip -6 addr delete 2001:44b8:4142:ae00::1:1 dev enp4s0
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address

root@host1:~# ip -6 addr show dev enp4s0
3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:44b8:4142:ae00:0:100:e:1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:44b8:4142:ae00::1:1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ae22:bff:fe28:9aea/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I forgot to include the /64 to make it work. My error was obviously an elementary beginner's error. But it suggests to me that there might be something wrong with the address string in your case. Just a wild guess. What you did should have worked.